# New shower install slow drain?

Tags: shower, drain, pipe

I had a pre-existing area remodeled to add a shower stall. Within a week the drain is extremely slow. Nothing has entered the new drain. It drains when I use a plunger, but continues to drain slowly right after. What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing the work did someone stick a rag in the drain to stop the gases from coming out? This is very common. Maybe it or a tool or debris got into the drain and stuck, maybe at the trap, maybe at a bend, and when you plunge the drain it is moved enough to drain the water but then settles back into place. Try snaking your drain to see if there is something in there

Comment: I will try it out. I’m thinking it’s a venting issue, I remember them mentioning a pre existing drain that they might use in the area. The house is also older , however this new drain is the only one having any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Is the drain line properly vented?  there should be a vent line for air a bit after the trap heading up, likely tying into the stack vent line going through the roof?
If the drain is within something like 4 feet of the main stack, you dont need a separate vent.
[image]